# Billing library on Android studio not showing

Tags: android-studio

I have been searching for an answer for a while now.
[Billing library on Android studio not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Onvi.png)
I already included on android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

On build gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
```

and

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.1.0'
```

But its not showing the option to install de Billing Library
Anyone who can help me please?

Comment: This is done automatically when building the app.

Comment: Hi Yoann, In all the tutorials i have seen you have to install the library from SDK Manager, but im not getting that option. Could you explain your answer a bit more? thanks

Comment: In the new versions of Android Studio you don' really need to use the SDK Manager anymore. All is done in the build.gradle files. What tutorial for example? The latest library is described here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview. Be careful not to install old versions since they are becomiong deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I can mark your comment as the correct answer (because its a comment), but im going to quote you, I was viewing an outdated tutorial in the spanish version of the official google documentation site. Apparently they aren't updating the documentation in all languages at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new versions of Android Studio you don't really need to use the SDK Manager anymore, all is done in the build.gradle files.
The latest library is described here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

Be careful to install the latest version since the previous ones are becoming deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Yoann Hercouet** for the correct answer: "In the new versions of Android Studio you don' really need to use the SDK Manager anymore. All is done in the build.gradle files."
Please note that, there are some out dated tutorials. I was viewing an outdated tutorial in the spanish version of the official google documentation site. Apparently they aren't updating the documentation in all languages at the same time.

Comment: Since it was actually the right answer I added it myself to clarify.